# What's wrong with sql query?

Tags: mysql, count

What I need to do is, to return today's registered user's count and activated users count (for today)
My query looks like that.

```
SELECT
    Count(u1.id) AS `registered`,
    Count(u2.id) AS `active`
FROM
    USER u1,
    USER u2
WHERE
    u1.registeredAt = CURDATE()
AND u2.active = 1;
```

What am I doing wrong that it returns 0 value for both?

Comment: can you provide the sql fiddle for it. That would help us to help you

Comment: do a query for each count and use `UNION`

Comment: What does your data look like? You have no condition explicitly joining the two tables, so you may not get the result you expect before applying the `COUNT()` aggregate to begin with.

Comment: You should join your tables first

Comment: But I agree with @SamD, it does look like you are intending to do a `UNION` instead of a self join. It could also be done with a `SUM(CASE)` for each in the select list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear with respect to the actual query.  First, I'll start with the date.  CURDATE() returns the date portion of whatever current date/time is, no problem.  However, you are asking for "RegisteredAt" = curdate().  Is the RegisteredAt stored as just a date, or full date/time.  If full date time, you should probably account via

where u1.RegisteredAt >= CURDATE()

so it gets everything since the beginning of the day, and since nobody should have a registeredAt date GREATER than today, you do not need to explicitly add AND u1.registeredAt < tomorrow.

Now, your consideration of "Active".  If this too is for the current date only, then adjust this to a IF() or case/when based on your preference and you only need the users table ONCE in the query

```
SELECT
    Count(u1.id) AS `registered`,
    sum( if( u1.active = 1, 1, 0 )) as ActiveToday
FROM
    USER u1
WHERE
    u1.registeredAt >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: +1 good point, easy to miss if in a rush but the condition should be the first thing to check

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code may be cross joining. Solution:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(id) FROM User WHERE registeredAt = CURDATE()) AS `registered`,
    (SELECT count(id) FROM User WHERE active = 1) AS `active`
```

Comment: Well I made some changes on your query SELECT
 (
  SELECT
   count(id)
  FROM
   User
  WHERE
   registeredAt = CURDATE()
 ) AS `registered`,
 (
  SELECT
   count(id)
  FROM
   User
  WHERE
   active = 1
  AND registeredAt = CURDATE()
 ) AS `active`  But the problem is, registeredAt is datetime. That's why it doesn't get right value

Comment: now() will return exact datetime for now/ But I need today's registrations

Comment: But you can use it like this: DATE(NOW())